# Perl and CPAN Sys::Virt - connect to vm console

Tags: perl, console, perl-module, kvm, libvirt

I'm using Sys::Virt CPAN module to "talk" to my kvm hypervisors and manage the domains. I can do nearly everything the noramlly used bash virsh command can do, except for virsh console, which (who would guess it) opens a text console to a domain. But whatever i do with sys::virt i just get a blinking cursor and nothing happens. I also am not able to find a single example on the whole wide web... So I thought i ask you what i am missing. Here is the code i have so far - and what i have tested:

```
use 5.010; 
use warnings; 
use Sys::Virt; 
use Sys::Virt::Stream; 

my $data; 
my $url = "someurl"; 

my $con = Sys::Virt->new('uri' => "qemu+tls://$url/system"); 
my $dom = $con->get_domain_by_name("name"); 
#Until here everything is just like in every other function i wrote. 

my $st = $con->new_stream(); 
$dom->open_console($st, undef); 
#I guess that i'm also fine until here - because there are no errors.. 

#And now i'm trying to do something with this stream object i made... 
#If i would type virsh console i would get a promt to log in, so i try to fetch this promt. 
#Here are two examples of how i was trying to get it: 

#Result of this block: Blinking cursor - no "test" 
my $rv = $st->recv($data, "1"); 
say "test"; 
say $rv; 
say $data; 

#Result of this block: Blinking cursor - no "test" 
$st->recv_all(sub{ 
    my ($st, $data, $nbytes) = @_; 
}); 
say "test"; 
say $st; 
say $data; 
say $nbytes;

$st->finish();
```

What am I missing - or doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: cross-post http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1054809

Comment: Yeah it is, because it's a difficult question, and i want to find at least one that can answer it. There is no tutorial and howto anywhere so i don't think many people are using it and I hope that there is at least one in both forums that uses this and can help! Because i really need help! As you can see - no answer here and no answer there nearly 24 hours after asking... So i had a reason, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok at last I found out what I am doing wrong, I just used the default stream. With an stream properly defined I can send and receive text.

```
my $st=$con->new_stream(Sys::Virt::Stream::NONBLOCK);
$dom->open_console($st, undef, 0);
```

When a stream is correctly defined and the program is not just taking the default - which evidently does not work - everything works just fine - very slow but fine.

Just in case someone has the same problem.